# Upgrading windows while keeping installed software

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

Recently, I have been having issues with booting Win10. I am getting a blue screen with the error code `0xc000021a`. Other startup options, such as safe mode, lead to the same error.

I have also tried the following commands, but without success:

```
BOOTREC /FIXMBR
BOOTREC /FIXBOOT
```

Therefore, I downloaded the Media Creation Tool for Windows 10 22H2 to upgrade Windows without losing my data (in-place upgrade). However, I receive the following message:

> The upgrade option isn't available, if you start your computer using
> Windows installation media.

While I can access all my data using a Linux live system, my primary concern are the programs that are already installed.

How can I repair Windows to continue using my programs?
Alternatively, is there a way to bring my installed programs to a fresh windows installation?

Comment: “How can I repair Windows to continue using my programs?” - You cannot. What you want is only possible IF AND ONLY IF you can boot into Windows. You can simply reinstall an application. Unless you can boot into Windows to run the Windows installer what you want is impossible

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1730691/windows-10-error-0xc000021a-after-ssd-upgrade) might help get you into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a corruption in Windows that prevents it from booting,
you may use SFC (System File Checker tool) to fix it from your
boot media, without using your unusable disk-installed Windows
(in offline mode).

Here is how :

- Boot the Windows installation from USB
- Click Next on the language screen
- Select *Repair your computer > Troubleshoot > Advanced Options >
  Command Prompt*
- Run `bcdedit` to locate the drive-letter of the disk where
  the unbooting Windows is installed
- Run the command

  ```
  sfc /scannow /offbootdir=<Windows_Drive_Letter>:\ /offwindir=<Windows_Drive_Letter>:\windows
  ```
- Wait for SFC to terminate
- Close the command prompt window and restart your computer
- If you now manage to boot into Windows, check the SMART status of the
  disk using a product such as
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy),
  to see if the disk is having serious problems.
  If serious problems are found, the disk needs to be replaced.
- Run `chkdsk`. If problems are found, backup your data before
  running `chkdsk /f`.
- To complete the recovery
  [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to Run SFC OFFLINE (System File Checker tool)](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-run-sfc-offline-system-file-checker-tool/).